# (Unity 5) Force child object to be perpendicular to the ground?

Tags: unity, rotation

[image]As i mentioned in the header, i want my MainCamera child object to stay perpendicular to the ground, any ideas?)

Comment: Does it have a rigidbody? Is your ground flat or do you have slopes?

Comment: I dont want it to be perpendicular to the ground normals. I just want to force it's X axis to 0, when Y is still attached to it's parent. Yes, it has a rigid body (coz it's carryable object).

Comment: What about the z-axis? Or is this a 2d project? Also, does it have a rigidbody or not?

Comment: Ok, i'll explain it. It's a 3d project. This object is one of the "Pickupable" objects, so when the player picks it up i want to force this object to stay horizontal. Z does not metter, coz player will never be turned in Z.

Comment: I provided a picture of what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform.eulerAngles` is in global rotation space. You attach a script to the child object that does this every update:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,transform.eulerAngles.y,0);
```

Comment: Doing this in `LateUpdate` will ensure it overrides any other `Update` scripts or animations affecting the object or its parent hierarchy earlier in the frame.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as i wanted it to work :)

InventoryItem[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);